# jupyterhub and Linux Data Science Virtual Machine on Azure.

Tags: azure, jupyterhub

i try with success Linux Data Science Virtual Machine on Azure and jupyterhub. It's start automatically the first time, but when restart jupyter doesn't start anymore.

what I could try to solve the problem?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JupyterHub automatically starts each time you start the VM, so it should be running after a restart. You can check the logs at a terminal with *journalctl -u jupyterhub*, and you can check the status of JupyterHub with *systemctl status jupyterhub*. You might try restarting the service with *systemctl restart jupyterhub*. It's also possible that you installed some software that broke the Jupyter kernel. See the notes [here](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd45057a-c3ec-4538-b7ae-3927274328ea/unable-to-load-kernel-from-jupyter-notebook?forum=dsvm) about a similar problem that someone else had.